# Ajax control Target id's for list new form.aspx controls?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, custom-list, ajax-control-tookit

I have done ajaxtoolkit v4.0 registration by following link. http://sampathnarsingam.blogspot.in/2012/05/how-to-make-ajax-control-toolkit.html

But I didn't understand how to insert my new ajax controls instead of regular list controls in list NewForm.aspx page.

There is no specific tag for textbox (or anyother control) for inserting ajax control tag instead of that. And every control did bind with list sharePoint:FormField and SharePoint:FieldDescription tags.

```
                    <tr>
                    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                            <nobr>Year<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
                            </nobr>
                        </H3>
                    </td>
                    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff3{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Year" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff3',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Year')}"/>
                        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff3description{$Pos}" FieldName="Year" ControlMode="New"/>
                    </td>                   

                </tr>
```

I just tried to put below tag under 2nd td above ..but not working. I didnt understand which id I have to pass as targetID?

```
<ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="ff3{$Pos}" WatermarkText="Enter year" />
```

suggestions please.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add ajax controls from the toolkit DLL in your toolbox on the left.
For this, create another category in the toolbox. Click add controls and select the controls from the popup.
You should be able to add ajax controls then just like you add normal asp controls via the toolbar.
Should not be a problem with the target IDs then.

Hope this helps

Comment: No Abhishek.. Im working on sharepoint 2013 oob not on VS.
anyway thank u for the reply.